# C error expected unqualified-id before 'if', 'else' and ' '{' token

Tags: c

I am writing a basic program in C++. I haven't programmed in C before, so I seem to be getting some fundamental errors.
The program is a small quiz. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
int correct = 0

{
  int q1;
  printf("What is 24/(6-3)-7?\n ");
  scanf("%d",&q1)
}
{
  int q2;
  printf("What is -3x4+16?\n ");
  scanf("%d",&q12)
}{
  int q3;
  printf("What is 9²(1/27)?\n ");
  scanf("%d",&q1)
}

if(q1 == 1){
  correct == correct + 1
}
if(){
} else if 
if(q2 == 4){
  correct == correct + 1
}
if(q3 == 3){
  correct == correct + 1
}
```

Please bear in mind that I have composed this of bits and pieces picked off the internet. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: First this is not [tag:c++], second this is not a program, it's just arbitrary code that should not compile. Read about scope!

Comment: You need `{ }` around the body of the function.

Comment: @Barmar That solved most of it. Now I am only getting expected unqualified-id  before '{' token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to put braces around the body of the function. And you shouldn't have braces around each block that asks a question -- that makes the variables like `q1` local to that block, so you can't use them later in the function.
2. Every statement **must** end with `;`.
3. `if()` is totally meaningless -- you have to put something inside the `()`; but I don't see the point of doing an extra check before checking the answer to question 2.
4. To update `correct`, you have to use `=`, not `==`; the latter is for comparison, not assignment. BTW, the idiomatic way to write `correct = correct + 1` is `correct++`.
5. Since `main()` is declared to return `int`, you should have a `return` statement at the end.
6. You had a bunch of typos. For instance, you used `&q12` and `&q1` when you meant `&q2` and `&q3` in your `scanf()` calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int correct = 0;

    int q1;
    printf("What is 24/(6-3)-7?\n ");
    scanf("%d",&q1);

    int q2;
    printf("What is -3x4+16?\n ");
    scanf("%d",&q2);

    int q3;
    printf("What is 9^(1/2)?\n ");
    scanf("%d",&q3);

    if(q1 == 1){
        correct = correct + 1;
    }
    if(q2 == 4){
        correct = correct + 1;
    }
    if(q3 == 3){
        correct = correct + 1;
    }

    printf("You got %d answers correct!\n", correct);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That has solved it and my program is compiling. I will be mindful of these errors in the future.
P.S. Sorry if the mistakes seem stupid, I am only 12 and just started programming. Thanks again!

Comment: It's good to see someone so young trying this. But you really do need to study the syntax in the tutorials more carefully. SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to know the real basics.

Comment: OK.. I will do that . Thanks for your help again.